# How do you pull specific objects from an arraylist?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism, overriding

I've made an Animal superclass, Shark and Whale subclasses.  What would I use to print out just the Shark objects from this arraylist?

Driver:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Creator {     
  public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<Animal> obj = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    obj.add(new Shark("James"));
    obj.add(new Shark("Mike"));
    obj.add(new Whale("Steve"));
    obj.add(new Whale("Tommy"));

    for (Animal a: obj){
    System.out.println(a.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `instanceof` to check for specific subclass from the list of superclass Animal

```
for (Animal a: obj){
   if(a instanceof Shark)
    System.out.println(a.getName());
}
```

Comment: i have written the same code but you posted it first !! anyway nice logic.

Comment: Thanks for the help over the first roadblock!

Answer (score 0):

Simple variant is just using `instanceof`. You can also create a `getType()` method in the base class, that will return, for example, a `enum` object or other entity to define the species in subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Use `instanceof`.
 From [JLS 15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)

> At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is `true` if the value of the RelationalExpression is not `null` and the reference could be cast to the ReferenceType without raising a ClassCastException. Otherwise the result is `false`.

Ex: Iterate over your `ArrayList`

```
if(yourObject instanceof Shark){
    System.out.println(yourObject.getName());
}
```