# Access a subclass method through an ArrayList of superclass objects?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

I have a superclass(Animal) and two subclasses(Frog and Lion). In my private method below, I'm creating three Lions and one Frog. I am displaying all four of the Animal's weight in my first loop, and all of the Lion's names in the second loop. I get the correct output, but my teacher told me "there is no need for creating two ArrayLists in your main method." I'm guessing he is suggesting that I use my first ArrayList to access the getName() method of my Lion Subclass.

This is how i did it and it was working:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class AnimalTest {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            ArrayList<Animal> animalList = createList();

            for(int i = 0; i < animalList.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(animalList.get(i).getWeight() + " lbs");
            } 

            ArrayList<Lion> lionList = createList();
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                System.out.println(lionList.get(j).getName());
            }

        }

        private static ArrayList createList(){
            ArrayList<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();

            list.add(new Lion("Leo I", 530.00));
            list.add(new Lion("Leo II", 560.00));
            list.add(new Lion("Leo III", 590.00));
            list.add(new Frog("Freddie", 7.00));

            return list;
        }

    }
```

Does he want me to access my getName() function from my Lion class through the same ArrayList list? I was thinking I could do this with some casting, like so:

```
//ArrayList<Lion> lionList = createList();
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
   System.out.println(animalList.(Lion)get(j).getName());
}
```

But this doesn't work.. I don't understand how I'm supposed to get to my Lion subclass's getName() method without creating a another ArrayList..

Here are the rest of my classes:

```
public class Animal {
    private String genus;
    private String species;
    private double weight;
    private boolean tail;

    public Animal(){}

    public Animal(String genus, String species){
        this.genus = genus;
        this.species = species;
    }

    public String getGenus(){
        return genus;
    }

    public String getSpecies(){
        return species;
    }

    public double getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight){
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public boolean hasTail(){
        return tail;
    }

    public void setTail(boolean tail){
        this.tail = tail;
    }

}


public class Lion extends Animal {
    private String name;

    public Lion(){}

    public Lion(String name, double weight){
        super("Panthera", "Leo");
        this.name = name;
        setWeight(weight);
        setTail(true);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}


public class Frog extends Animal {
    private String name;

    public Frog(){}

    public Frog(String name, double weight){
        super("Lithobates", "Catesbeianus");
        this.name = name;
        setWeight(weight);
        setTail(false);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do frogs also have names (as in "Freddie the frog")? And perhaps also a `getName()` method? Your teacher may be suggesting that you move the `getName()` method to the `Animal` class.

Comment: Yes Frogs also have a getName() method. The instructions specifically said not to have anything about the Animals' names in the Animal class, however..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parent class cannot access the fields or methods of a child class, since it has no knowledge of what it has implemented.

With that in mind, the logical thing to do is place what you need to access in the `Animal` class instead.  This means that you're going to pull the `name` field up into the parent `Animal` class and access it there instead.

Then, you only require one `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Animal> animalList = createList();
for(Animal animal : animalList) {
    System.out.println(animal.getWeight());
    System.out.println(animal.getName());
}
```

Further, two ***very important*** changes to your `createList` method need to happen:

- **Do not return a raw `ArrayList`.  Ever.**  You need to type it correctly.

  ```
  public ArrayList<Animal> createList() { }
  ```
- You should not care about it being an `ArrayList` or a `List`.  It's preferable (although not required) to program to the interface of `List` instead.

  ```
  public List<Animal> createList() { }
  ```

  For bonus points, you could prevent mutations of the list either by making it immutable or using PECS:

  ```
  public List<? extends Animal> createList() { }
  ```

Comment: @JakeFromStateFarm, So, the assignment doesn't state that you can't have anything referencing the name in the Animal class? Reference your comment: "...The instructions specifically said not to have anything about the Animals' names in the Animal class, however.."

Comment: @nihilon Correct, the assignment only mentions adding the name in the specific Animals' subclasses. Although I don't see how he wants me to do it, I have tried casting and everything. Honestly I think he doesn't realize what his own instructions said, lol. I think Makoto is right, the parent class doesnt really know anything about the child class's fields or methods. I'm going to ask my instructor in person on Monday. He sent me this message online and it was very vague.

Comment: Unless he wants you to use an interface, that is.  But that'd be a bit silly, considering that you've *already* got a common object to reference.

Comment: @JakeFromStateFarm, What Makoto said. And you were right to select Makoto's answer. IMHO, based on that instruction, you could legitmately build an argument contradicting it, and be right. With code examples. I had built out a similar answer in detail when I saw that comment and started trying to rethink it, only to realize that it wasn't going to be possible without some serious black magiks and voodoo, if you will. If the instructions only mention the name in the subclasses, I don't think it would be wrong to go this route. Don't forget the bonus points piece, but make sure you understand it

Comment: Yes I'm definitely going to argue with my instructor on this one, lol! I may even post here again after I talk to him. Anyways, you guys have super helpful. Thanks for the info on raw return types and using the List class too.

Comment: Apologies if I'm wrong but I thought you can do this with instanceOf? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30022874/1358857

Comment: @GideonSassoon:  That's not the same thing here.  That would require a cast from the parent class to the child class, which does not have any bearing on whether or not the parent class is aware of any of the child class' methods or fields.

Answer (score 1):

Your `createList` function is return a [raw-type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). **Please**, don't do that. Also, I recommend you program to the interface. But your second example `lionList` would seem to need a `createLionList` method. Something like,

```
private static List<Lion> createLionList() {
    List<Lion> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Lion("Leo I", 530.00));
    list.add(new Lion("Leo II", 560.00));
    list.add(new Lion("Leo III", 590.00));
    return list;
}
```

Then we can modify the first `createList` to add it. Something like,

```
private static List<Animal> createList() {
    List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(createLionList());
    list.add(new Frog("Freddie", 7.00));
    return list;
}
```

In your `main` method, I would prefer a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). And [formatted output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). Something like,

```
List<Animal> animalList = createList();
for (Animal a : animalList) {
    System.out.printf("Weight: %d lbs, Name: %s", a.getWeight(),
            a.getName());
}
```

Comment: You mean my method signature should be ArrayList<Animal> return type instead of just ArrayList? Is using "List" instead of "ArrayList" the same thing? Also, thanks for your idea with the foreach loop, that makes sense since I'm just printing all of the Animals and not a select few.

Comment: @JakeFromStateFarm that is essentially what he means. But using `List` as the return type rather than `ArrayList` means that later on you can change the `ArrayList` to `LinkedList`, or some other implementation of `List` with minimal modification to the rest of the code, if any is necessary at all. That is less directly related than it is a free tip.

Comment: @JakeFromStateFarm, that sounds like it is the case. However, if you've covered `ArrayList`, you aren't a long shot off from covering `List`. Think about it in terms of your classes. A `Lion` is an implementation of `Animal`, in the same way that `Frog` is. They are both `Animal`s, but they are more specific in form and function, and therefore have more specific methods, fields, etc. Does that make sense?
In that way, `ArrayList` is an implementation of `List`. It is more specific in both form and function, but has things in common with other implementations.

Comment: @nihilon I agree that it's good practice, but i can't remember the last time i went back and changed the type of List implementation i originally chose.

Comment: @EricGuan, Then our experience differs. I've been in a situation where production code where the list implemenation changed from `ArrayList` to `LinkedList`, and finally to a custom implementation within the first 3 months of development. By the time the custom imp rolled around, if I hadn't been in the habit of returning the plain old thing, I would have had to have refactored something like 10+ methods, and every single call/assignment in the program. IMHO, it's more than just a 'good practice'. It can directly affect the budget, which in turn affects job security. I am just sayin'.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, you've just got the syntax for the cast wrong. Try:

```
((Lion)animalList.get(j)).getName()
```

Although if both frogs and lions can have names, it would make more sense to just put the `getName()` in the `Animal` class.

Comment: This seems right, but it is not working either.. It says it cannot find getName() in the Animal class. It should be looking in the Lion class not the Animal class with this casting though, correct?